# Custom Backstage View Tab like standard tab FileNew

Tags: ms-office, office-2007, office-2010

I want to design own custom backstage view tab that has desing like standard tab FileNew. 
How can I (and can I at all) use such tab elements like scrollable button set or large borderless button with text at bottom of one.
[image: Sample]

Answer (score 1):

There are elements in the BackStage Tabs which are built-in and not available form the programming side. For example, all the individual controls on the Print Backstage Tab cannot be re-used by a developer. I'm afraid that we have the same problem with the File New Backstage. The previews are built-in. You can verify this if you look into the WordControls.xlsx file delivered with the Office 2010 Control-IDs download: There are no controls for the TabNew except for "GroupNewFormTemplates", "GroupNew2003Dialog" and "GroupNewFormPreview". 
You can only re-use controls which are defined in the Ribbon Scheme, as Combobox, Edit Control, Button, and so on.

So to display your templates, you must use these default controls, or built something completely different.

Comment: I was afraid of this answer. And it's very woefully. BTW, on "built something completely different" U keep in mind don't use Backsatge or is a way to build custom control in backstage tab?

Comment: ... and what is the WordControls.xlsx file? It is absent on my computer and looking for it in Google was unsuccsessful.

Comment: Oh, sorry. You can download this reference from MSDN. In [this file](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=3F2FE784-610E-4BF1-8143-41E481993AC6) you'll find the Control IDs for all Office Applications.

Comment: With "something completely different" I will say that you can use either a backstage UI using the Office controls, or you display an own Windows Forms / WPF dialog if the user clicks "New" - without backstage.